# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: spring

Currently I am new to spring to trying to implement data-source with MySQL but I am facing a error but not able to understand what is main reason or error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError    
Apr 26, 2015 8:09:33 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4ee70b: startup date [Sun Apr 26 20:09:33 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.rajdeo.jdbcspring.JdbcDemo.main(JdbcDemo.java:12)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:104)
        ... 7 more
```

JdbcDemo.java

```
package com.x.jdbcspring;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.x.jdbcspring.JdbcDaoImpl;

public class JdbcDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        JdbcDaoImpl dao=ctx.getBean("JdbcDaoImpl",JdbcDaoImpl.class);

        /*
        //JdbcDaoImpl dao=new JdbcDaoImpl();
        Student student=ctx.getStudent(1);
        System.out.println("name::\t"+student.getName());

        JdbcDaoImpl jdbc=new JdbcDaoImpl();
        jdbc.getStudent(1);

        System.out.println(jdbc.getStudent(1).getId());*/
    }
}
```

JdbcDaoImpl.java

```
package com.x.jdbcspring;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class JdbcDaoImpl {


    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;


    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        return datasource;
    }


    public void setDatasource(DataSource datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }


    public Student getStudent(int id){

        Connection  con = null;
         Student student=null;
           try{
        /*      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              System.out.println("Connecting to database...");*/
              con = datasource.getConnection();
              PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from contact where contact_id =?");
              stmt.setInt(1, id);

              //Excute the query
              ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
              while(rs.next()){
                  String name=rs.getString("name");
                  student=new Student(id, name);
              }

            //close the statement and Resultset
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();

            return student;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally{
            if(con!=null)
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }       
        return student;
    }

}
```

Student.java

```
package com.rajdeo.jdbcspring;

public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Student(int id, String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.rajdeo" />

<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxx" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

What is error I am not able to understand it any help is appreciated.

Comment: @nikpon what is NPE??? can you elaborate.

Comment: NPE = java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Do you get the error when you run the commented out code? because line 12 is `JdbcDaoImpl dao=new JdbcDaoImpl()` but it is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting a bean from the context

```
ctx.getBean("JdbcDaoImpl",JdbcDaoImpl.class)
```

but in the `spring.xml` this bean is not defined. As a result you get NPE = `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

To resolve this issue you have to configure [`JdbcDaoImpl`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/core-services.html#core-services-jdbc-user-service) service. E.g.

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxx" />
</bean>    
<bean id="JdbcDaoImpl"
      class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
  <property name="datasource" ref="datasource"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `spring.xml` says to scan the package `com.rajdeo` for components, but your class `JdbcDaoImpl` is in package `com.x.jdbcspring` and so it will not be picked up, even though it has a `@Component` annotation.

Make sure to include the package that contains `JdbcDaoImpl` in the component scanning process:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.rajdeo, com.x.jdbcspring" />
```